Count how often two keys are matching (SQL)
For example, I have the following table:
| comment_ID     | comment_author   | comment_author_email
| -------------- | ---------------- | ---------------------- |
| 100            | Max              | max@gmail.com          |
| 101            | Max              | max2@gmail.com         |
| 102            | Pierre           | pierre@gmail.com       |
| 103            | Max              | max@gmail.com          |
| 104            | Sam              |                        |
| 105            | Max              | max@gmail.com          |

The result / output of my SQL request should be:
Max: 3
Max: 1 /* because of the different email */
Pierre: 1
Sam: ignore (because no email exists)

My problem:
With the following SQL request, I can get the count of one specific user (the logged-in user):
global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_var('
SELECT COUNT(comment_author)
FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. '
WHERE comment_author_email = "' . get_comment_author_email() . '"');
echo $count . ' comments';

BUT: How to get the count of all comments per user (by name + email), instead of only the logged-in one?

I think what you want here is:
SELECT comment_author, comment_author_email, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM comments
WHERE comment_author_email IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY comment_author, comment_author_email;

If you don't need the email, then remove it from the select clause.

Hi Tim, thx for your support. Its not working for me. ;( With this, I just get one "author_name" as result.

And one more question, "$wpdb->get_var()" instead of "$wpdb->get_results()" is correct, right? And I use "mariadb", is that also working for it?

You either aren't running my code, or else you are not using the same data in your question above.

I do, but is it maybe a problem if some "comment_author_email" keys are empty?

Please edit your question to reflect this data/edge case and we can go from there.

Alright, I have updated it. And it seems like, that the "empty" key is the problem.

Thx for your update, but again, I only get one author name as result and not a list with counts. Totally strange ;( ...

The problem may be lost in translation in the PHP code rather than the query.

Yes, think so too. ;( But thx for your help so far! I will dive into the rest of my code and take a look. Have a nice day.

Check this demo which uses your sample data.

@TimBiegeleisen I confirm that your last code (edit) works, just like the OP wanted (note that WordPress db table name start by default with "wp_").

@TimBiegeleisen If found the error, but I still got no solution: "WordPress-Database-Error: []
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'https_migration_required' LIMIT 1". No plugins active, no "functions.php" active, and also a new reinstallation of WordPress doesn't fix it. ;(

Different problem, you should open a new question.  This is not a blog site.

@TimBiegeleisen Ignore my last comment, it's working now. Big thx again.
